# MongoDB aggregate by created_at months

Tags: mongodb, time-series, aggregation-framework

I have a collection full of entities and I'm working on using MongoDB aggregations to offload some of the work that my backend process does.
I managed to convert a lot of endpoints, I'm missing one that generates data for my timeline.

I'm using the following code snippet in my aggregation to retrieve the format that I need for my object:

```
{ $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$created_at' } }
```

what I would be able to achieve is the following result from the aggregation:

```
"timeline": {
   "by_month": {
        "2023-04": 5000,
        "2023-03": 7000,
        "2023-02": 10000,
        "2023-01": 0,
        "2022-12": 0,
        "2022-11": 1000,
        "2022-10": 2000,
        "2022-09": 3000,
        "2022-08": 1000,
        "2022-07": 500,
        "2022-06": 200,
        "2022-05": 700
    },
}
```

based on some conditions that I specify in the aggregation.

The field **by_month** of course needs to be added, maybe with an **$addFields** instruction in the aggregation.

The hard parts for me are:

- Create MongoDB object keys from the $dateToString result
- Create a by_month key even for months without entries

is it possible to achieve this directly from an aggregation? Right now I'm looping over entities with a cursor but performances are really poor.

For example, given the following sample documents:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-04-02T11:53:19.779+00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "created_at": "2023-03-02T11:53:19.779+00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "created_at": "2023-01-02T11:53:19.779+00:00"
  }
]
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
"timeline": {
   "by_month": {
        "2023-04": 1,
        "2023-03": 1,
        "2023-02": 0,
        "2023-01": 1,
        "2022-12": 0,
        "2022-11": 0,
        "2022-10": 0,
        "2022-09": 0,
        "2022-08": 0,
        "2022-07": 0,
        "2022-06": 0,
        "2022-05": 0
    },
}
```

The answer is amazing, however if we have something like the following entities:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-03-02T12:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-01-02T12:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "created_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T12:53:19.779Z"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2023-04-02T13:53:19.779Z")
  }
]
```

it's possibile to group by different keys in the same query and obtain the following result?

```
"timeline": {
   "created_by_month": {
        "2023-04": 2,
        "2023-03": 1,
        "2023-02": 0,
        "2023-01": 1,
        "2022-12": 0,
        "2022-11": 0,
        "2022-10": 0,
        "2022-09": 0,
        "2022-08": 0,
        "2022-07": 0,
        "2022-06": 0,
        "2022-05": 0
    },
  "updated_by_month": {
        "2023-04": 4,
        "2023-03": 0,
        "2023-02": 0,
        "2023-01": 0,
        "2022-12": 0,
        "2022-11": 0,
        "2022-10": 0,
        "2022-09": 0,
        "2022-08": 0,
        "2022-07": 0,
        "2022-06": 0,
        "2022-05": 0
    },
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            $dateTrunc: {
               date: "$created_at",
               unit: "month"
            }
         },
         count: { $count: {} }
      }
   },
   {
      $densify: {
         field: "_id",
         range: {
            step: 1,
            unit: "month",
            bounds: [ISODate("2022-05-01"), ISODate("2023-04-01")]
         }
      }
   },
   { $fill: { output: { count: { value: 0 } } } },
   {
      $project: {
         by_month: {
            k: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$_id' } },
            v: "$count"
         }
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: null, by_month: { $push: "$by_month" } } },
   { $project: { _id: 0, timeline: { by_month: { $arrayToObject: "$by_month" } } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hKeJ5n61-l3)

**Update**

With a limited number of fields, you can use `$facet` to group multiple fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $facet: {
         created_at: [
            {
               $group: {
                  _id: {
                     $dateTrunc: {
                        date: "$created_at",
                        unit: "month"
                     }
                  },
                  count: { $count: {} }
               }
            },
            {
               $densify: {
                  field: "_id",
                  range: {
                     step: 1,
                     unit: "month",
                     bounds: [ISODate("2022-05-01"), ISODate("2023-04-01")]
                  }
               }
            },
            { $fill: { output: { count: { value: 0 } } } },
            {
               $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  by_month: {
                     k: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$_id' } },
                     v: "$count"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         updated_at: [
            {
               $group: {
                  _id: {
                     $dateTrunc: {
                        date: "$updated_at",
                        unit: "month"
                     }
                  },
                  count: { $count: {} }
               }
            },
            {
               $densify: {
                  field: "_id",
                  range: {
                     step: 1,
                     unit: "month",
                     bounds: [ISODate("2022-05-01"), ISODate("2023-04-01")]
                  }
               }
            },
            { $fill: { output: { count: { value: 0 } } } },
            {
               $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  by_month: {
                     k: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$_id' } },
                     v: "$count"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         created_at: { $first: "$created_at" },
         updated_at: { $first: "$updated_at" }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         _id: 0,
         timeline: {
            created_at: { $arrayToObject: "$created_at.by_month" },
            updated_at: { $arrayToObject: "$updated_at.by_month" }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Very elegant and clean!

Comment: it is possible to group also into multiple groups?

Comment: Yes, you can. Please open a new question for that.

Comment: I can't at the moment, my account is limited